# Default Azure ADDS password policy maximum age set to 10 years

Tags: azure-active-directory

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/password-policy) document, the defaults for Azure AD user account passwords are as follows:

- Account lockout duration: 30
- Number of failed logon attempts allowed: 5
- Reset failed logon attempts count after: 2 minutes
- Maximum password age (lifetime): 90 days

The same document also details the steps to add a fine-grained policy. Checking the default policy that was created, it looks like this:

[image: Default Azure AD password policy]

which shows that the *Enforce maximum password age* value is set to **36500**.

Is the maximum password age actually 10 years? Or, is it just showing this value since it has not been set, and its actually 90 days, as per the Microsoft doc?

Comment: Its very Strange maximum password age value is between 1 to 999 days. How is it showing for you 36500 days as a default? : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/maximum-password-age

Comment: I think that's my question... since that value "isn't set" by some overriding policy, does it just show some value here? Or is that the actual value then?

Comment: May be there is some overriding policy thats forcefully set this value. It should show 90 days the default vaule.

Comment: As i cannot test.Can you please check for other users? Does it showing 90 days or somethimg else ?

Answer (score 0):

The default value of Maximum Password Age is 90 days as per Microsoft document but it is showing for you 36500 days because someone from `member of the AAD DC Administrators group` has created a custom password policy and it has applied to all users. That could be the reason you are seeing this as 36500 days.

> Note: Password policies can only be applied to groups

Please refer the section of **Create a custom password policy** of the same [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/password-policy) you were.

Comment: There is no custom password policy set. Only the default exists.

Comment: In that case would suggest you to reach out to azure support they can able to track why it is showing unexpected behavior: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/support/create-ticket/